# using gulp on cloud 9

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gulp, cloud9

I am currently going through a course on udemy with cloud 9 and so far things have been smooth. However gulp doesn't seem to work. Gulp watch doesn't work which I've been ignoring so far but now I'm at a point where I can't really continue without getting this to work and I can't really do anything because the gulp scripts command isn't working. This is the error I get:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/js/scripts.js' in
>   '/home/ubuntu/workspace'

From webpack --display-error-details:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/js/scripts.js' in
>   '/home/ubuntu/workspace' resolve
>   './wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/js/scripts.js' in
>   '/home/ubuntu/workspace'   using description file:
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/package.json (relative path: .)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file: /home/ubuntu/workspace/package.json
>   (relative path: .)
>       using description file: /home/ubuntu/workspace/package.json (relative path:
>   ./wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/js/scripts.js)
>         no extension
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/js/scripts.js
>   doesn't exist
>         .js
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/js/scripts.js.js
>   doesn't exist
>         .json
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/js/scripts.js.json
>   doesn't exist
>         as directory
>           /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/js/scripts.js
>   doesn't exist

Unfortunately I don't know what any of this means so I can't fix it.

Comment: Try removing the forward slash in the settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the folder where gulp is found and run these two lines

```
npm uninstall ws
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

This will update it to the latest. I have done the same course and this solves the problem.

Also have a look in webpack.config.js

Change the line

```
App: settings.themeLocation + "js/scripts.js"
```

to

```
App: __dirname + '/'+settings.themeLocation + "js/scripts.js"
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work. If it helps when I run gulp scripts, it creates an empty folder in my themes folder named fictional-university. I tried changing my existing one to that (with the "-" instead of "_") but that resulted in nothing being displayed when I visit the site.

Comment: That sounds like you have the wrong path set up. It shouldn't actually create fictional-university but it should create scripts-bundled.js and style.css in the main folder. I think that you need to double check your path in the settings.js file